# Fields loaded as read only in civicrm.settings.php

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

The database was upgraded from 5.37.1 to 5.39.0 by Civihosting. When I went to check the resource urls as suggested I am receiving "Some fields are loaded as 'readonly' as they have been set (overridden) in civicrm.settings.php.

Any suggestions of what I need to change to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is set in the civicrm.settings.php file. It's perfectly fine to do overrides: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/#override-settings-in-civicrmsettingsphp.

Comment: I am new to all this is this a setting I need to change?

Comment: You do not need to do anything and CiviHosting should handle regardless